# Given the value of a polynomial mod $611953$, find $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

Given a polynomial of degree $n$, and a value $\pmod{611953}$, find the possible $x$ at which this value occurs?

For example a polynomial $p(x)$ is given of some degree $n$, and a number is given which is the result of evaluating the polynomial at some point say $a$, then find $a$.

Note: the value is given mod $611953$.

Comment: Consider $p(x)=x$ and the value given being $0$. How do you distinguish between $x=0$ and $x=611953$? (etc.) At least $\{x\colon p(x)=a\}$ is finite for each $a$ (assuming $n\geq 1$).

Comment: You can can even have the polynomial $$f(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{611952} (x-i).$$ Then $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{611953}$ for all integers $x$.

Comment: Or $x(x^{611952}-1)$ of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$611953$ happens to be prime.  Assuming the polynomial has integer coefficients, $f(x) \equiv f(y) \mod 611953$ if $x \equiv y \mod 611953$.  So at worst you have $611953$ values to search through: not hard for a computer.

Comment: That's what i was also thinking, but is there any property on which i can perform binary search, to see if i am on some correct value ? Actually the degree of polynomial is also quite large so i dont want to check by evalutaing the polynomial again and again.

Comment: I don't know how a binary search could help.

Comment: You could use a CAS such as Maple or Mathematica to solve (polynomial $=$ value) mod $611953$.   Solving a polynomial mod a prime is not something you can easily program yourself.